# Can a Pyeryem Mage Talk to a Black/Porte Wolf?

Tags: 7th-sea

I am aware by reading the description that the black wolves/porte wolves in the Montaigne book says that they were once normal wolves now driven insane by being brought through a porte walk.  However, I have a character at my table that's a full blooded Pyeryem, and she can turn into a wolf to boot.  The player's first reaction to animal related troubles (especially as Pyeryem) is to talk to them and try to reason with them.

So my core question is **can a Pyeryem use their Speak knack to talk to a Porte Wolf?**  Just how far gone are they?  Because even feral animals have a voice.

Edit: When the moment came I used Xabei's comment.  I used the Intimidate action from Repartee whenever she tried to talk to it and expressed that its mind is simply a grindhouse of malice.  In future adventures I will likely include siren whispers from beyond the gates.

> I would also have have speaking with the crazed wolf have a Repartee effect on the player, most probably Taunt or Intimidate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If character has the ability to speak to a normal wolf, and tries to speak to an irrevocably insane one, he should probably have no more trouble than in speaking with an inhabitant of an asylum - technically possible, but in no way easy.

I'd suggest *Speak* + *Wits* roll to succeed in understanding or communicating something. The TN is up to you - decide how hard should it be and set accordingly.

Comment: I would also have have speaking with the crazed wolf have a Repartee effect on the player, most probably Taunt or Intimidate.

Comment: Currently both the answer and Jeor's suggestion are at thr forefront.  However, I'm concerned about the wolf being so insane that it doesn't even think in "higher" concepts.

Comment: @CatLord The wolves have a reasonable Wits score (2), and basic tactics (attack from behind). This suggests they're at least as intelligent as an extremely simple animal, such as a lizard. Personally, I'd also allow Pyeryem mages to speak with them, but twist their motivation enough to make compromise difficult. On the other hand, you could get a lot of mileage out of the "Porte has robbed them of everything, including their voices" angle. Particularly given the antipathy between Porte and Pyeryem.